# I keep getting IllegalStateException when running Azure Application Insights agent with my Spring Boot app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, azure-application-insights, performancecounter

My Spring Boot app runs fine and logs are pushed to Azure Application Insights correctly. But I keep seeing IllegalStateException due to Unmapped Relationship, filling up my console exactly every minute. I am unable to figure out what is the cause of this ERROR. Following is the full stacktrace. if anyone has an idea how to fix or suppress this.

```
java -javaagent:C:\Users\********\Documents\HUB\Java\hub_api\build\applicationinsights-agent-3.1.1.jar -jar C:\Users\********\Documents\HUB\Java\hub_api\build\libs\hub_api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
2021-09-03 13:40:14.714+05 INFO  c.m.applicationinsights.agent - ApplicationInsights Java Agent 3.1.1 started successfully

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::       (v2.6.0-SNAPSHOT)

2021-09-03 13:40:17.343  INFO 6496 --- [           main] c.h.HubApplication                       : Starting HubApplication using Java 11.0.12 on DESKTOP-******* with PID **** (C:\Users\********\Documents\HUB\Java\hub_api\build\libs\hub_api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by husarkar in C:\Users\********\Documents\HUB\Java\hub_api)
2021-09-03 13:40:17.359  INFO 6496 --- [           main] c.h.HubApplication                       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-09-03 13:40:18.964  INFO 6496 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-09-03 13:40:19.073  INFO 6496 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 94 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-09-03 13:40:20.050  INFO 6496 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.e.t.TomcatWebServer              : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-09-03 13:40:20.078  INFO 6496 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.StandardService                  : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-09-03 13:40:20.079  INFO 6496 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.StandardEngine                   : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.52]
2021-09-03 13:40:20.200  INFO 6496 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/api]                     : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-09-03 13:40:20.200  INFO 6496 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2756 m 
2021-09-03 13:40:20.774  INFO 6496 --- [           main] o.h.j.i.u.LogHelper                      : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-09-03 13:40:20.932  INFO 6496 --- [           main] o.h.Version                              : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.5.6.Final
2021-09-03 13:40:21.277  INFO 6496 --- [           main] o.h.a.c.Version                          : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-09-03 13:40:21.536  INFO 6496 --- [           main] c.z.h.HikariDataSource                   : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-09-03 13:40:23.563  INFO 6496 --- [           main] c.z.h.HikariDataSource                   : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-09-03 13:40:23.626  INFO 6496 --- [           main] o.h.d.Dialect                            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
2021-09-03 13:40:24.936  INFO 6496 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2021-09-03 13:40:24.950  INFO 6496 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-09-03 13:40:25.417  WARN 6496 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2021-09-03 13:40:25.970  INFO 6496 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.e.t.TomcatWebServer              : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path '/api 
2021-09-03 13:40:25.981  INFO 6496 --- [           main] c.h.HubApplication                       : Started HubApplication in 9.538 seconds (JVM running for 13.477)
2021-09-03 13:41:13.942+05 ERROR c.m.a.i.p.PerformanceCounterContainer - Exception while reporting performance counter 'JSDK_OshiPerformanceCounter'
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unmapped relationship: 7
        at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT$SYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION_EX.fromPointer(WinNT.java:3033)
        at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32Util.getLogicalProcessorInformationEx(Kernel32Util.java:715)
        at oshi.driver.windows.LogicalProcessorInformation.getLogicalProcessorInformationEx(LogicalProcessorInformation.java:61)
        at oshi.hardware.platform.windows.WindowsCentralProcessor.initProcessorCounts(WindowsCentralProcessor.java:155)
        at oshi.hardware.common.AbstractCentralProcessor.<init>(AbstractCentralProcessor.java:74)
        at oshi.hardware.platform.windows.WindowsCentralProcessor.<init>(WindowsCentralProcessor.java:66)
        at oshi.hardware.platform.windows.WindowsHardwareAbstractionLayer.createProcessor(WindowsHardwareAbstractionLayer.java:60)
        at oshi.util.Memoizer$1.get(Memoizer.java:87)
        at oshi.hardware.common.AbstractHardwareAbstractionLayer.getProcessor(AbstractHardwareAbstractionLayer.java:68)
        at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.internal.perfcounter.OshiPerformanceCounter.report(OshiPerformanceCounter.java:60)
        at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.internal.perfcounter.PerformanceCounterContainer$1.run(PerformanceCounterContainer.java:231)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
2021-09-03 13:42:13.597+05 ERROR c.m.a.i.p.PerformanceCounterContainer - Exception while reporting performance counter 'JSDK_OshiPerformanceCounter'
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unmapped relationship: 7
        at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT$SYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION_EX.fromPointer(WinNT.java:3033)
        at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32Util.getLogicalProcessorInformationEx(Kernel32Util.java:715)
        at oshi.driver.windows.LogicalProcessorInformation.getLogicalProcessorInformationEx(LogicalProcessorInformation.java:61)
        at oshi.hardware.platform.windows.WindowsCentralProcessor.initProcessorCounts(WindowsCentralProcessor.java:155)
        at oshi.hardware.common.AbstractCentralProcessor.<init>(AbstractCentralProcessor.java:74)
        at oshi.hardware.platform.windows.WindowsCentralProcessor.<init>(WindowsCentralProcessor.java:66)
        at oshi.hardware.platform.windows.WindowsHardwareAbstractionLayer.createProcessor(WindowsHardwareAbstractionLayer.java:60)
        at oshi.util.Memoizer$1.get(Memoizer.java:87)
        at oshi.hardware.common.AbstractHardwareAbstractionLayer.getProcessor(AbstractHardwareAbstractionLayer.java:68)
        at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.internal.perfcounter.OshiPerformanceCounter.report(OshiPerformanceCounter.java:60)
        at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.internal.perfcounter.PerformanceCounterContainer$1.run(PerformanceCounterContainer.java:231)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
2021-09-03 13:43:13.611+05 ERROR c.m.a.i.p.PerformanceCounterContainer - Exception while reporting performance counter 'JSDK_OshiPerformanceCounter'
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unmapped relationship: 7
        at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT$SYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION_EX.fromPointer(WinNT.java:3033)
        at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32Util.getLogicalProcessorInformationEx(Kernel32Util.java:715)
        at oshi.driver.windows.LogicalProcessorInformation.getLogicalProcessorInformationEx(LogicalProcessorInformation.java:61)
        at oshi.hardware.platform.windows.WindowsCentralProcessor.initProcessorCounts(WindowsCentralProcessor.java:155)
        at oshi.hardware.common.AbstractCentralProcessor.<init>(AbstractCentralProcessor.java:74)
        at oshi.hardware.platform.windows.WindowsCentralProcessor.<init>(WindowsCentralProcessor.java:66)
        at oshi.hardware.platform.windows.WindowsHardwareAbstractionLayer.createProcessor(WindowsHardwareAbstractionLayer.java:60)
        at oshi.util.Memoizer$1.get(Memoizer.java:87)
        at oshi.hardware.common.AbstractHardwareAbstractionLayer.getProcessor(AbstractHardwareAbstractionLayer.java:68)
        at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.internal.perfcounter.OshiPerformanceCounter.report(OshiPerformanceCounter.java:60)
        at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.internal.perfcounter.PerformanceCounterContainer$1.run(PerformanceCounterContainer.java:231)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
2021-09-03 13:44:13.585+05 ERROR c.m.a.i.p.PerformanceCounterContainer - Exception while reporting performance counter 'JSDK_OshiPerformanceCounter'
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unmapped relationship: 7
        at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT$SYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION_EX.fromPointer(WinNT.java:3033)
        at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32Util.getLogicalProcessorInformationEx(Kernel32Util.java:715)
        at oshi.driver.windows.LogicalProcessorInformation.getLogicalProcessorInformationEx(LogicalProcessorInformation.java:61)
        at oshi.hardware.platform.windows.WindowsCentralProcessor.initProcessorCounts(WindowsCentralProcessor.java:155)
        at oshi.hardware.common.AbstractCentralProcessor.<init>(AbstractCentralProcessor.java:74)
        at oshi.hardware.platform.windows.WindowsCentralProcessor.<init>(WindowsCentralProcessor.java:66)
        at oshi.hardware.platform.windows.WindowsHardwareAbstractionLayer.createProcessor(WindowsHardwareAbstractionLayer.java:60)
        at oshi.util.Memoizer$1.get(Memoizer.java:87)
        at oshi.hardware.common.AbstractHardwareAbstractionLayer.getProcessor(AbstractHardwareAbstractionLayer.java:68)
        at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.internal.perfcounter.OshiPerformanceCounter.report(OshiPerformanceCounter.java:60)
        at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.internal.perfcounter.PerformanceCounterContainer$1.run(PerformanceCounterContainer.java:231)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
2021-09-03 13:45:13.548+05 ERROR c.m.a.i.p.PerformanceCounterContainer - Exception while reporting performance counter 'JSDK_OshiPerformanceCounter'
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unmapped relationship: 7
        at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT$SYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION_EX.fromPointer(WinNT.java:3033)
        at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32Util.getLogicalProcessorInformationEx(Kernel32Util.java:715)
        at oshi.driver.windows.LogicalProcessorInformation.getLogicalProcessorInformationEx(LogicalProcessorInformation.java:61)
        at oshi.hardware.platform.windows.WindowsCentralProcessor.initProcessorCounts(WindowsCentralProcessor.java:155)
        at oshi.hardware.common.AbstractCentralProcessor.<init>(AbstractCentralProcessor.java:74)
        at oshi.hardware.platform.windows.WindowsCentralProcessor.<init>(WindowsCentralProcessor.java:66)
        at oshi.hardware.platform.windows.WindowsHardwareAbstractionLayer.createProcessor(WindowsHardwareAbstractionLayer.java:60)
        at oshi.util.Memoizer$1.get(Memoizer.java:87)
        at oshi.hardware.common.AbstractHardwareAbstractionLayer.getProcessor(AbstractHardwareAbstractionLayer.java:68)
        at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.internal.perfcounter.OshiPerformanceCounter.report(OshiPerformanceCounter.java:60)
        at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.internal.perfcounter.PerformanceCounterContainer$1.run(PerformanceCounterContainer.java:231)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Answer (score 0):

> 2021-09-03 13:41:13.942+05 ERROR c.m.a.i.p.PerformanceCounterContainer
>
> - Exception while reporting performance counter 'JSDK_OshiPerformanceCounter' java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Unmapped relationship: 7
>   at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT$SYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION_EX.fromPointer(WinNT.java:3033)
>   at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32Util.getLogicalProcessorInformationEx(Kernel32Util.java:715)

Based on the above shared stack error message looks like an issue with   "**Windows is adding new Relationship values to LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_RELATIONSHIP enum** " & this issue is actively discussing over the below  git hub community.
https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/issues/1324

I would suggest you go through it & update the git hub discussion if you are facing the issue.