# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unmapped relationship: 7

Tags: java, jar, slf4j

So I purchased some files from this guy, and when I tried opening the .bat file, which the instructions say to do, it opened cmd with this long error message. So then I went on a long internet search, but everyone says to edit the bat file or XML, etc... but keep in mind I bought this file, and I don't want to screw it up. DOES anyone have a solution for the error? Im hoping it has to do with my java platform and not the file I bought bc I spent 9 euros on the program, and the guy I bought it from is offline, so I chose StackOverflow and created this account for this question. Pls, help!

````
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unmapped relationship: 7
        at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT$SYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION_EX.fromPointer(WinNT.java:3033)
        at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32Util.getLogicalProcessorInformationEx(Kernel32Util.java:715)
        at b.xLA.qH(LogicalProcessorInformation.java:61)
        at b.PPA.0G(WindowsCentralProcessor.java:155)
        at b.hPA.<init>(AbstractCentralProcessor.java:74)
        at b.PPA.<init>(WindowsCentralProcessor.java:66)
        at b.AIA.IM(WindowsHardwareAbstractionLayer.java:60)
        at b.nMA.get(Memoizer.java:87)
        at b.QNA.WA(AbstractHardwareAbstractionLayer.java:68)
        at b.NMA.8QA(Unknown Source)
        at b.TMA.2Q(Unknown Source)
        at b.NMA.8QA(Unknown Source)
        at b.JKA.rR(Unknown Source)
        at b.JKA.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at fun.spamis.client.SpamIsFun.tR(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)```
````

Comment: The SLF4J messages are just warnings you can ignore, the relevant part is the exception. What Java version do you use (version and architecture and which Java distribution)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69041741/i-keep-getting-illegalstateexception-when-running-azure-application-insights-age -> Ask the person you got the software from.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem. I searched a lot of knowledge on the Internet but I couldn’t get started. I don’t know why, but I found the problem after checking jna. I don’t know why it is like this. After I upgraded the jna version to 5.10.0, I sent him that there seems to be no problem, but I couldn’t find the cause of the problem

```html
<dependency>
                <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
                <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
                <version>5.10.0</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
                <artifactId>jna-platform</artifactId>
                <version>5.10.0</version>
            </dependency>
```